# DecimalFormat not working when locale changed to indonesia

Tags: android, localization, decimalformat

I am developing an app that support different languages .I use DecimalFormat class to format double value. The method below works fine for all languages except indonesia. I appreciate for any help.

```
 public static String formatNumberWithCommaSeparated(Double number){

    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00");
    String FormattedString = formatter.format(number);
    return FormattedString;
}
```

Result

> formatNumberWithCommaSeparated(125.0);
>
> -In English,Malay,Thailand,Chinese => 125.00
>
> -In Indonesia Language => 125,00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually is working because formatter is based on Locale so, you need to add a default Locale like in UK which is dot and not a comma.

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) nf;

    {
        df.applyPattern("##.00");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.00",Locale.ENGLISH);
```